# How do I create a public IP address for my AWS ALB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My EC2 instance has an endpoint Public DNS name which works fine.

However, there's no public IP address attached to it.

How do I set this up so that I can point our DNS records to it?

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Use the Public DNS name as a CNAME record.
2. Setup an [Elastic IP Address](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) and use it in an A record.

The advantage of a CNAME is that there are no limits. Elastic IPs have limits - I think 5 per account, though that may have changed and there may be ways to get more. The advantage of an Elastic IP is that you can move it around between instances while keeping your DNS record pointing to the same IP address.

This assumes you already have NS records pointing somewhere where you can configure DNS. If you don't have DNS set up and you want to do everything in AWS then you can use [Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/).

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks about IP addresses for ALB and IP addresses for EC2 instances. Similar topics but very different use cases.

If you want to setup a domain name to point to an EC2 instance, add / use an Elastic IP address to your EC2 instance. Do not use the Public DNS endpoint.

If you instead want to attach your EC2 instances to your ELB, then you will specify the EC2 instance ID when configuring the load balancer. The load balancer will use the private IP address to communicate to the EC2 instances.

The following is my comments on setting up IP addressing for EC2 instances. This is NOT required for EC2 instances behind load balancers.

> You cannot manually associate or disassociate a public IP address from
>   your instance. Instead, in certain cases, we release the public IP
>   address from your instance, or assign it a new one:
>
> 1. We release the public IP address for your instance when it's stopped or terminated. Your stopped instance receives a new public IP
>      address when it's restarted.
> 2. We release the public IP address for your instance when you associate an Elastic IP address with your instance, or when you
>      associate an Elastic IP address with the primary network interface
>      (eth0) of your instance in a VPC. When you disassociate the Elastic IP
>      address from your instance, it receives a new public IP address.
> 3. If the public IP address of your instance in a VPC has been released, it will not receive a new one if there is more than one
>      network interface attached to your instance.
>
> If you require a persistent public IP address that can be associated
>   to and from instances as you require, use an Elastic IP address
>   instead.

[Public IPv4 Addresses and External DNS Hostnames](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses)

[Elastic IP Addresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html)

Comment: I tried to associate an new elastic IP with my instance. I can't access through the new elastic IP. Only the instances Public DNS name.

Comment: We are using an ALB load-balancer

Comment: The Load balancer has an DNS Name, but no IP address. So how do I access it ?

Comment: E.g. I'm trying to test this with my hosts file, but that doesn't recognise the DNS name.

Comment: @AdamHarkus use `dig` or `nslookup` to find the current public IP address**es** of your load balancer (they almost always have at least two).  Pick any one of them, and put it in your hosts file for testing... but do not use these for DNS configuration, since they will change when the balancer scales or does maintenance.

Comment: To access the load balancer you use the DNS name. In Route53 configure an "A - ALIAS" record using the DNS endpoint. Load balancers do have public IP addresses (more than one) but these addresses change over time. The actual ways that the load balancer's addresses change is a big topic for a different question.

Comment: That's worrying about the IP changing. I take it this force me to go down the Route 53 route?

Comment: Yes, you will need to resolve the load balancer's IP address with DNS. Route53 is an excellent choice. Amazon load balancers are clusters of systems. They grow, shrink, expand, ... based upon traffic load and the number of availability zones used by the EC2 instances. They are normally not a single system. I am over simplifying, but do not use IP addressing, use the DNS endpoint.

Comment: I've looked into it and we already have a route53 A ALIAS pointing to the ALB.  They all have a .local suffix though and including this Name in my host file doesn't work. Only the direct IP works.

Comment: For your .local suffix. Is this a Private Hosted Zone? Notice the word "private".